# How do I use multiple decision statement in shell?

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to check if multiple file exists in the shell script but I am not sure how it works.

I have tried

```
#!/bin/bash
path=/home/test
        cd $path
        if [ -f "a.txt"] || [ -f "b.txt" ] || [ -f "c.txt" ] || [-f "d.txt"]
        then
                echo "one of the file exist"
        else
                echo "non of the file exist"
        fi
```

I am getting

```
line 4: [: missing ']'
```

I saw people uses double brackets but that only works if it is for bash not for POSIX

Comment: put **;** at the end of the if and leave a white space between **[..]**

Comment: [ -f "d.txt" ]; I changed to this but I am still getting line4: [: missing ']'

Comment: this too is wrong **[ -f "a.txt"]**

Comment: oh wow, I cant believe I didnt spot that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really is more obvious if you stop trying to use the spelling `[`.  Just write:

```
if test -f "a.txt" || test -f "b.txt" || test -f "c.txt" || test -f "d.txt"; then ...
```

or, (this is obsolete usage, and should not be used.  Thanks to @chepner for pointing this out), you can do:

```
if test -f a.txt -o -f b.txt -o -f c.txt -o -f d.txt; then ...
```

Also, if you are willing to trust the vagaries of your shell (which is to say that even though the standard specifies that `set -f` will cause the shell to disable pathname expansion, I wouldn't trust every shell to behave as expected), you can do:

```
set +f; if ! test [abcd].txt = '[abcd].txt' 2> /dev/null; then ...
```

Comment: would it be okay if I use wild cards in the file parameter as -f *.txt instead? I was wondering if the syntax would be the same the quotes for the wild card worries me

Comment: No.  Suppose a.txt and c.txt both exist.  In that case, under normal conditions (eg, it depends on certain settings in the shell) `test -f *.txt` is the same as writing `test -f a.txt c.txt`, which will generate an error.  If none exist, `test -f *.txt` will test for the existence of a file named `*.txt`

Comment: I got the error "command test not found" if i remove the brackets

Comment: `-o` is considered obsolete and only option in the POSIX spec; use separate `test` commands joined by `||` instead.

Comment: @javaneophyte What shell are you using? `test` should absolutely be available.

Comment: @chepner I typically avoid `-a` and `-o` but I hadn't realized it was actually obsolete.  Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @chepner Never mind. It's right there, marked OB in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/.

Comment: Here's a direct link: [Rationale for dropping `-a` and `-o`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16). I don't really like how the spec is presented using frames; it makes it hard to link to specific sections.

Answer (score 1):

You have to type a blank between the quotation mark and the closing bracket as well as between the opening bracket and the parameter. The right syntax is:

```
if [ -f "a.txt" ] || [ -f "b.txt" ] || [ -f "c.txt" ] || [ -f "d.txt" ]
```

Not

```
if [ -f "a.txt"] || [ -f "b.txt" ] || [ -f "c.txt" ] || [-f "d.txt"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that in `[ -f "a.txt"]` the closing square bracket is treated as part of the string, i.e `[ -f "a.txt]"`, so you need to add a space before the closing square bracket: `[ -f "a.txt" ]`.

Same with the opening brackets. The `[-f "d.txt"]` will be parsed as `"[-f" "d.txt]"`, so you have to add space after the opening and before the closing square bracket here: `[ -f "d.txt" ]`.